# Syntactic fontification of diff hunks

Tags: diff-mode, polymode, multiple-modes, mmm-mode

I'm looking for a multiple-major-modes package that doesn't remove fontification of the host mode from its inner submodes?

I tried [MMM Mode](https://github.com/purcell/mmm-mode) and [Polymode](https://github.com/vspinu/polymode), but they remove the initial fontification and put own faces with own background colors in regions with submodes.

What I'm trying to achieve is to fontify diff hunks in `diff-mode` syntactically according to the rules of their source code language, e.g. to highlight their keywords like it's done on diff pages of version control web sites like github/gitlab.

multiple-major-modes packages are able to detect diff hunks and their source language from file extensions in the diff header, find the corresponding major mode using `auto-mode-alist`, and fontify these diff hunks accordingly as submodes. But they don't keep fontification of `diff-mode` with faces `diff-added` and `diff-removed` that highlight changes using different background colors.

Is there a package that can do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is implemented now in Emacs 27 and available by default using the variable `diff-font-lock-syntax`.

Comment: Could you expand your answer to show how to configure it?

Comment: Actually there is no need to configure it, because it's enabled by default.

Comment: Great!  Could you just add that point to your answer for future readers?